# How to use Akka with transactions across email and database?

Tags: akka

I have a situation where I have a component with a list of users. I need to send an email to each user, and then update the user's record to indicate the time when the email was sent.

This seems like a good first use-case for Akka. I was thinking the component that gets the list of users would be an Actor, and a separate Actor would be created for each outbound email-sending Actor, which could be multithreaded. The email-sending Actor would be responsible for updating the date in the user record.

If the email-sending Actor failed, the user's record wouldn't be done, and the supervising Actor would be able to reschedule it.

Is that the right model? Or should the supervisor be responsible for updating the user record?

Or is this a bad use-case for Akka completely?

BTW, I could send mail via SMTP or a web service. I don't think it matters much for the discussion, but I thought I'd mention it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you should get hung up on transactionality when there's IO involved. You have no guarantees that the emails will be read, received, received by the right person, received within a certain period of time, be understood etc.

Just send the email and then update the database.
Happy hAkking!